Fire base exception : missing or insufficient permissions - flutter ,firebase
I'm developing a E learning platform for learning purpose and stuck with this when i'm adding the data that are required for adding a course.I already configured firebase and added users collection in the user side. I dont have authentication for admin, its just hard coded with certain values as user name and password,
thanks in advance.
Missing or insufficient permissions.

rules_version = '2';

// Craft rules based on data in your Firestore database
// allow write: if firestore.get(
//  /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

this is my database rules code.
and below is my course adding bloc

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

part 'course_event.dart';
part 'course_state.dart';

class CourseBloc extends Bloc<CourseEvent, CourseState> {
  CourseBloc() : super(CourseInitial()) {
    on<AddCourseEvent>(addCourseToFirebase);
    on<EditCourseEvent>(editCourseToFirebase);
    on<DeleteCourseEvent>(deleteCourseToFirebase);
  }
FutureOr<void> addCourseToFirebase(
  AddCourseEvent event,
  Emitter<CourseState> emit,
) async {
  emit(LoadingState()); // Emit the LoadingState before starting the upload

  try {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("courses")
        .doc(event.CourseId)
        .set(event.data)
        .then((value) {
      print("add course success");
    });
  } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
   ** print("add course: ${e.message}")**;
  }
}
  FutureOr<void> editCourseToFirebase(
      EditCourseEvent event, Emitter<CourseState> emit) async {
    try {
      print(event.CourseId);
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("courses")
          .doc(event.CourseId)
          .update(event.data)
          .then((value) {
        debugPrint("edit course success");
      });
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("editCourse ${e.message}");
    }
  }

  FutureOr<void> deleteCourseToFirebase(
      DeleteCourseEvent event, Emitter<CourseState> emit) async {
    try {
      print(event.CourseId);
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("courses")
          .doc(event.CourseId)
          .delete();
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("editCourse ${e.message}");
    }
  }
}



what should i do
I've tried changing the rules and find pout setting true is the best option while developing

You claim to get an error message from accessing Firestore, but the security rules you included in your question are for Cloud Storage. Those two product are completely separate, and while the security rules syntax is the same - the rules for one don't apply to the other.
So you'll want to configure the rules for Firestore in the Firebase console. I also recommend not just setting them to allow all-public access (as that sets you up for abuse), but to follow the guidance in the documentation on avoiding insecure rules.
